# Заходить 100 раз подряд на сайт — это важный вклад участника в развитие сообщества?

Tags: обсуждение, знаки, фанатик, золотые-знаки

В разделе `знаки` написано:

> Золотые знаки вручаются за важный вклад участника в развитие
>   сообщества. Они довольно редкие.

И у нас есть знак `Фанатик` который гласит: "Посещать сайт ежедневно в течение 100 дней подряд". Это важный вклад участника в развитие сообщества?

Comment: Уточните, а что вам не нравится?

Comment: добавьте в автозагрузку selenium скрипт. И через 100 дней получите знак. Так можно очень иного наград получить. Например знаки за количество голосов и тревог

Comment: @AndrioSkur Точно.. я же программист...чего я раньше не догадался..

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Если вы просто отмечаетесь раз в день в течении 100 дней - то нет. Но в этом отмечании смысла нет, вы же если будете заходить, то будете что то полезное делать для сайта. Думаю, тут в этом и смысл - знаки мотивируют нас делать что то, что может прямо, а может и косвенно влиять на развитие сайта. Например, знак "Информированный" - сайту прямой пользы нет от того, что вы что то прочитали, но косвенная польза есть от того, что больше людей знают правила сайта.

Answer (score 25):

А вы попробуйте 100 дней подряд заходить на сайт. Это неизбежно превратится в привычку. Stackoverflow станет не просто каким-то сайтом, а частью вашей жизни. Это изменяет отношение, сложно не вносить вклад в свою собственную жизнь.

Comment: Как обладатель подобного знака, не могу с Вами не согласиться)

Answer (score 13):

Как по мне создатели сделали Геймификацию, а это очень нравится людям. Типа "о как круто у меня много знаков, надо получить ещё чтобы быть ещё круче".
Как-то так

Answer (score 4):

> Золотые знаки вручаются за важный вклад участника в развитие сообщества. Они довольно редкие.

Так и есть. А его не так просто получить. На каком-то этапе может что-то произойти, к примеру вы без интернета сутки и всё, история с данным знаком закончилась. У меня так было ) Я конечно был настойчивый и заработал его честным трудом, как на основном сайте, так и на Мета.

Самое главное, что принес этот знак, так это привычку пользоваться именно данным ресурсом для поиска вопросов и ответов в области программирования или системного администрирования, а не каким-то другим.

> Посещать сайт ежедневно в течение 100 дней подряд

Да, сначала это кажется ерундой, но постепенно, посещая StackOverflow ежедневно, пользователь осознанно или нет, начинает вносить свою лепту. Кто-то вопросами или ответами, кто-то модерацией и в процессе человек проникается общей философией организации и остается с ней надолго. В какой-то момент я заметил, что даже отвечая кому-то из окружающих на вопрос типа: "а где я могу найти ответ на вопрос по программированию?" - отвечал: "StackOverflow".

Comment: Сначала начал отвечать на вопросы, потом решил получить этот знак(пол года назад). В итоге было около 80и дней - потом в какой то момент все сбилось. Я психанул, решил перестать заходить сюда каждый день(это минимум каждый день, на самом деле я раз в 3-4 часа захожу, а летом вообще решил поднабрать репутации - так просто открыл вопросы по метке в отдельной вкладке и смотрел, не появится ли там значок (1))  Так  вот, решил я недавно опять попробовать получить этот знак - около месяца(может больше) каждый день заходил(хотя я и так почти каждый день заходил сюда, но не регулярно)

Comment: - недавно смотрю - опять подряд посещений всего 8. Не хватает моего терпения - кто-то что писал про селениум скрипт в автозагрузке, пойду погуглю.

Comment: О чём я и написал, не так-то легко это :)

Comment: Завтра думаю получу знак, только если вдруг интернет не отключат :)

Comment: @VerNick первое золото - самое ценное

Comment: @L.F.C.  Ура, получил :)

Comment: @VerNick а теперь на Мета повторить успех )))

Comment: @L.F.C. Попробую :)